# AWS Versioning - batch/mass restore to last version that isn't 0kb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, versioning, batch-processing, restore

I made a very foolish error with a large image directory on our server which is mounted via S3FS to an EC2 instance and I ran Image_Optim on it. It seemed to do a good job until I noticed missing files on the website, which when I looked id noticed were files which had been left at 0kb...

...Now fortunately I have versioning on and a quick look seems to show at the exact same time on all the 0kb files is the correct version as well.

It has happened to about 1300 files in a 2500 directory. Question is, is it possible for me to batch process all the 0kb files and tell them to restore to the latest version that is bigger than 0kb??

The only batch restore tool I can find is S3 Browser but that causes you to restore all files in a folder to their latest version. In some cases this would work for the 0kb files but for many it won't, I also don't own the program so would rather do it with a command line script if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Once your file(s) have become 0 bytes or 0kb, you cannot recover them, well at least not easily. If you mean restore / recover from ext. Backup then that will work.

Comment: Its a pain because the correct versions of them are there - there should be an easier way for versioning to work in S3 otherwise its kind of pointless except for on a handful of files.